# jQuery UI Resize won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I can't get the Resize aspect of jQuery UI to work, everything else works just fine.

I've look at several solutions listed on this site, and I've tried them all.  It seems like the re-sizeable classes, and all the required elements are being added.  I never see a handle or have the actual ability to resize.

Please take a look and let me know what I'm missing... if anything.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="canvas.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>



    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {


var activeFrame = "#frame1";

    $(function() {
        $( "#assets" ).accordion();
    });

    $(".preview").click(function(event) {
        console.log("Frame backdrop set to " + event.target.id);
        $(activeFrame).removeClass();
        $(activeFrame).addClass(event.target.id);
    });

    $(".prop").click(function(event) {
        console.log("User added " + event.target.id + "_full");
        $(activeFrame).append('<div id="' + event.target.id + '_full" class="drag "></div>');
    propPrep();
    });

    function propPrep(event) {
        $( ".drag" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
        $( "#" + event.target.id + "_full").resizable({ aspectRatio: 16 / 9});
    }

});
    </script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="assets">
    <h3>Backdrops</h3>
        <div id="backdrops">
            <div id="bd1" class="preview"></div>
            <div id="bd2" class="preview"></div>
            <div id="bd3" class="preview"></div>
        </div>
    <h3>Props</h3>
        <div id="props">
        <div id="garfield1" class="prop"></div>
        </div>
    <h3>Characters</h3>
        <div id="characters">test</div>
</div>
<div id="strip">
    <div id="frame1"></div>
    <div id="frame2"></div>
    <div id="frame3"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: pass the event in prop() like `prop(event)`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the argument event to the prop function

Change

```
$(".prop").click(function(event) {
..
    propPrep();
});
```

to

```
$(".prop").click(function(event) {
   ....
    propPrep(event);
 });
```